# Finding Generators of O( Z^3,x^2 + xy + y^2 - z^2) and integer solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms, lattices

All pythagorean triples can be generated from $(3,4,5)^T$ and $(5,4,3)^T$ by the matrices:

\[ A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 2 & 2 \\\\ -2 & 1 & 2 \\\\-2 & 2 & 3 \end{array} \right) \hspace{0.25in}
B = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 2 \\\\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\\\2 & 2 & 3 \end{array} \right) \hspace{0.25in}
C = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 2 \\\\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\\\2 & -2 & 3 \end{array} \right) \]

Giving pythagorean triples the structure of a ternary tree.  These correspond to generators of $\mathrm{O}(\mathbb{Z}^3, x^2+y^2-z^2)$ and we're looking for integer points on the ``light cone" where the norm is zero.

I remember seeing there being 5 generators for the quadratic $x^2 + xy + y^2 = z^2$.  Does anyone have the reference?

Comment: I see, you need severa automorphs of $x^2 + x y + y^2 - z^2.$ Meanwhile, rather than primes $ \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ For this problem you want primes $z \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ So your first triple would be $(3,5,7)^T$

Comment: how might I find the lattice corresponding to a quadratic form $x^2+xy+y^2-z^2$ ?  What is the lattice for $x^2+y^2-z^2$ ?

Comment: John, as in my answer, the Gram matrix $G$ for the original Pythagorean triples would be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $ (1,1,-1).$ You should check, for your three matrices above, that $$A^T G A = G, \; B^T G B = G, \; C^T G C = G,$$ which is what you want if you are writing your triples as column vectors, as I do. If it turns out you are using row vectors, similar check with the transposes of your three matrices instead.

Comment: @John, there are two problems with your description of the orthogonal group of $x^2 + y^2 - z^2$. First, the vector [5,4,3] isn't even a zero of that quadratic form. Typo? Second, why do you say these three matrices generate the orthogonal group? I think you're forgetting to look at stabilizer subgroups too. For example, the diagonal matrix diag(-1,1,1) is in the orthogonal group. Can you write it in terms of your three matrices? I know five generators of that orthogonal group, not three. 

Comment: This might be in Allcock's paper "The reflective Lorentzian lattices of rank 3". 
http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/allcock/

Comment: @Keith, I should fix the typo.  I guess the correct statement is "the orbits of (3,4,5) and (4,3,5) by multiplication of these 3 matrices generate all positive pythagorean triples"  You need a few more to get the entire orthogonal group but these are normal subgroups or something, switching halves of the "light-cone".

Comment: Somewhere, earlier this summer I read a note deriving the pythagorean triple tree from Euclidean geometry.  Towards the end it showed there were 5 matrices generating solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2-z^2=0$ probably as consequence of Law of Cosines.  Now I can't find it.

Comment: John, evidently your version is due to Berggren (1934), anyway see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple 


Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120.C2.B0_angle 

suggests four possible articles, 
# ^ Gilder, J., Integer-sided triangles with an angle of 60°," Mathematical Gazette 66, December 1982, 261 266
# ^ a b Burn, Bob, "Triangles with a 60° angle and sides of integer length," Mathematical Gazette 87, March 2003, 148–153.
# ^ a b Read, Emrys, "On integer-sided triangles containing angles of 120° or 60°", Mathematical Gazette 90, July 2006, 299-305.
# ^ Selkirk, K., "Integer-sided triangles with an angle of 120°," Mathematical Gazette 67, December 1983, 251–255

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't call it GL, it is the orthogonal group of the lattice we are discussing. References, as i said, include *Lattices and Codes* by W. Ebeling, *Rational Quadratic Forms* by Cassels, these two being available and inexpensive.

We double the quadratic form to get an integral Gram matrix:

$$ G \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  2 & 1 & 0 \\\
  1  & 2 & 0 \\\
  0 & 0  & -2  
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

Your solutions, the light cone, are column vectors $v$ such that $ v^T G v = 0.$ A root, since we have doubled everything to get an "even" lattice, is a vector $r$ with norm 2, $ r^T G r = 2.$ The general definition of reflection (Cassels calls this a symmetry, page 19) in any vector $w$  is that 
$$ x \mapsto \; \; x \; -  \; \frac{2 \, x^T G w}{w^T G w} \; w.$$
As a result, when we take $w$ to be a root, the factors of 2 cancel and we are taking lattice points to other lattice points. In your original form, a root $(x,y,z)$ solves $x^2 + x y + y^2 = 1 + z^2.$ Then the reflection in the root is just a linear map, determinant $-1,$ and is therefore given by a square matrix with respect to the original basis. Finally, the reflection is an isometry, part of the orthogonal group of the quadratic form, and if we call the matix $A,$ it solves $$A^T G A = G.$$

I think it wise to include reflection in the root  $(1,0,0)^T$ to get some negative values taken care of,
$$ A_0 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & -1 & 0 \\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

We also include reflection in the root  $(0,1,0)^T,$ 
$$ A_{00} \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\\
-1 & -1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

Note that we have already included the automorph that interchanges the first two items, $$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (y,x,z). $$

$$ A_0 A_{00} A_0 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

Although it may not be called a root, having norm $-2,$ we include reflection in  $(0,0,1)^T,$ or
$$ A_{000} \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

Also, as is usual, we explicitly include  negation,
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (-x,-y,-z), $$ so 
$$ A_{0000} \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & -1 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

It occurred to me that we would get some reflections with quite small matrix entries by taking other vectors of norm $-2,$ for example $(1,1,2)^T.$
$$ A_{-1} \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
4 & 3 & -4 \\\
3 & 4 & -4 \\\
6 & 6 & -7
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$ This still solves, as with all the $A'$s, both $A^T G A = G$ and $A^2 = I.$

Taking the root $(3,4,6)^T$ gives the reflection 
$$ A_1 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
 -29 & -33 & 36 \\\
-40 & -43 & 48 \\\
-60 & -66 & 73 
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

If we take the initial triple in the light cone to be $c = (3,5,7)^T,$ we get $A_1 c = (0,1,1)^T$ which is indeed another solution, and shows that care must be used in constructing the "tree."

Taking the root $(5,15,18)^T$ gives the reflection 
$$ A_2 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-124 & -175 & 180 \\\
-375 & -524 & 540 \\\
-450 & -630 & 649
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$ 
we get $A_2 c = (13,35,43)^T$

Taking the root $(8,19,24)^T$ gives the reflection 
$$ A_3 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-279 & -368 & 384 \\\
-665 & -873 & 912 \\\
-840 & -1104 & 1153
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$ 
we get $A_3 c = (11,24,31)^T$

Taking the root $(7,32,36)^T$ gives the reflection 
$$ A_4 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-321 & -497 & 504 \\\
-1472 & -2271 & 2304 \\\
-1656 & -2556 & 2593
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$ 
we get $A_4 c = (80,357,403)^T$

Taking the root $(12,47,54)^T$ gives the reflection 
$$ A_5 \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
-851 & -1272 & 1296 \\\
-3337 & -4981 & 5076 \\\
-3834 & -5724 & 5833
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$ 
we get $A_5 c = (159,616,709)^T$

One typically includes $\pm 1$ anyway. Ian Agol would know how many reflections are enough, but I suspect this will do. Nothing really wrong with finding too many.
Note that the squarefree parts in $1+z^2$ in the five nontrivial roots I chose are $37, 13, 577, 1297, 2917.$